# SQL retrieve info from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a question about sql and i need to know if i can retrieve results using only sql.

I need to find the distance in km of the route with the id=1 that starts from station 1 and arrive at station 4. So route 1 will pass from 4 stations (the number could be more or less). I need to find the distance that a train will cover crossing all the 4 stations. Which are: 5+10+15=30

is it possible to get the answer using only SQL?

below are the tables (i hope you understand the structure):

you can see an image of the table [here](http://studio9.com.cy/testing/sql.gif)

```
route - station
-----------------------
1     - 1    
1     - 2    
1     - 3    
1     - 4


station1 - station2 - distance (km)
------------------------------------
1        - 2        -   5
2        - 3        -   10
3        - 4        -   15
```

Comment: How is the order of the station visits determined for a route? What flavour of sql are you using (ie can analytic functions be used)?

Comment: This could be done with a recursive CTE, but that's not available in all database systems.

Comment: am using Microsft SQL server management studio. Lets assume that the order is defined by the order showed in the table

Comment: as far as I know, I don't think there's a way to work this out using pure SQL

Comment: does the couple (station1, station2) belong only to one route?

Comment: @rano, no. they can belong to many routes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but there are a -lot- of assumptions on the ordering of the stations, how the distances are defined, etc. This is just an example of an approach (and using Postgresql):

```
create table route(route_id int, station_id int);
create table distance(station1_id int, station2_id int, km int);

insert into route values(1, 1);
insert into route values(1, 2);
insert into route values(1, 3);
insert into route values(1, 4);

insert into distance values(1, 2, 5);
insert into distance values(2, 3, 10);
insert into distance values(3, 4, 15);


select route_id, sum(km)
  from (select route_id, station_id
              ,lead(station_id) over(partition by route_id order by station_id) AS next_station_id
          from route
       ) a
      ,distance d
  where d.station1_id = a.station_id
    and d.station2_id = a.next_station_id
  group by route_id;
```

Sample output:

```
postgres=# select route_id, station_id
postgres-#               ,lead(station_id) over(partition by route_id order by s
tation_id) AS next_station_id
postgres-#           from route;
 route_id | station_id | next_station_id
----------+------------+-----------------
        1 |          1 |               2
        1 |          2 |               3
        1 |          3 |               4
        1 |          4 |
(4 rows)


postgres=# select route_id, station_id, next_station_id, d.km
postgres-#   from (select route_id, station_id
postgres(#               ,lead(station_id) over(partition by route_id order by s
tation_id) AS next_station_id
postgres(#           from route
postgres(#        ) a
postgres-#       ,distance d
postgres-#   where d.station1_id = a.station_id
postgres-#     and d.station2_id = a.next_station_id;
 route_id | station_id | next_station_id | km
----------+------------+-----------------+----
        1 |          1 |               2 |  5
        1 |          2 |               3 | 10
        1 |          3 |               4 | 15
(3 rows)


postgres=# select route_id, sum(km)
postgres-#   from (select route_id, station_id
postgres(#               ,lead(station_id) over(partition by route_id order by s
tation_id) AS next_station_id
postgres(#           from route
postgres(#        ) a
postgres-#       ,distance d
postgres-#   where d.station1_id = a.station_id
postgres-#     and d.station2_id = a.next_station_id
postgres-#   group by route_id;
 route_id | sum
----------+-----
        1 |  30
(1 row)


postgres=#
```